# Last row of a value that matches IN or OUT status

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to write a code to show the user is IN or OUT on the google deployed web app.

The data is recorded in the Google sheet as seen in the screen shot
[image]

What Im trying to do is to show the status of an employee on the web-app is he IN or OUT based on the google sheet records.

Here is my code

```
//Status in/out

function statusIdication(){
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var employee = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName;
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();        
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColoum = mainSheet.getLastColumn();
  
  
  for (var j = 1; j <= lastRow; j++){
    var mainSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN").getRange(j,5).getValues();
    var mainSheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN").getRange(j,1).getValues();
    var status = (mainSheet2 =="IN" && mainSheet3 == employee) ; 
    if (status = true){
      var notification = "IN";
      Logger.log(notification);
    }
    else{
      var notifaction2 = "OUT"; 
    }
    
  }
  
  
}
```

Example -  If last entry of Employee **Peter = IN** then return status as `IN` or else `OUT`.

I'm not sure where i went wrong, I'm getting an empty out put.

Comment: `status = true` to `status == true`

Comment: @Marios Still the same :(

Comment: you have one more issue. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues:

As far as I can see you have the following **two** issues:

- In the `if` condition you are using an assignment operator `=` instead of equality operator `==`. Because you assign the value `true` to `status`, the first `if` block statements gets executed everytime.
- The second issue has to do here:

  ```
  var mainSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN").getRange(j,5).getValues();
  var mainSheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN").getRange(j,1).getValues();
  var status = (mainSheet2 =="IN" && mainSheet3 == employee) ;
  ```

  You are using `getValues` but this returns a **2D** array. You should use `getValue()` instead because you are referring to a single cell. As a result the comparison in the last line will work as well.

Note that you are using `ss.getSheetByName("MAIN")` three times. It is a good practice to use the variable you stored it, otherwise you make unnecessary calls.

### Solution:

```
function statusIdication(){
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var employee = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName;
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();        
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColoum = mainSheet.getLastColumn();
  
  
  for (var j = 1; j <= lastRow; j++){
    var mainSheet2 = mainSheet.getRange(j,5).getValue();
    var mainSheet3 = mainSheet.getRange(j,1).getValue();
    var status = (mainSheet2 =="IN" && mainSheet3 == employee) ; 
    if (status == true){
      var notification = "IN";
      Logger.log(notification);
    }
    else{
      var notifaction2 = "OUT"; 
    }
    
  }
  
  
}
```

**Optimized solution:**

Get the full data instead of iteratively calling `getRange` and `getValue`:

```
function statusIdication(){

 var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var employee = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName;
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();        
 var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
 var data = mainSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 
   for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
    var row = data[j];
    var mainSheet2 = row[4];
    var mainSheet3 = row[0];
    var status = (mainSheet2 =="IN" && mainSheet3 == employee) ; 
    if (status == true){
      var notification = "IN";
      Logger.log(notification);
    }
    else{
      var notifaction2 = "OUT"; 
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, Still i'm getting an empty out put :(

Comment: why don't you `Logger.log(mainSheet2)` and `Logger.log(mainSheet3)` before the `if` condition to see what  values they contain? Also do `Logger.log(employee)` because that also might be causing the issue. To make the console log more clear for debugging purposes, run the `for` loop until `j=5` or something like that. You don't need to run it until the bottom of the sheet for troubleshooting. @Miyer

Comment: I added a code line under if condition IN as return notification;

Boom It worked :)

Comment: I'd add the suggestion to `getValues()` for all the rows and then just loop through the resulting array, instead of calling `getValue()` in a loop: [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Comment: @Iamblichus I added an optimized version. I can't test it, but it should work. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed a small typo: indexes had to be changed since arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: @Iamblichus thanks for the correction, but I put `j=1` on purpose because `j=0` is the header row. But anyway, the headers will never evaluate to `true` so both ways would work.

Comment: Oops sorry for that, I just looked at the OP's code and didn't check there were headers. Also, I changed the `row[0]`, `row[4]`, I think that's ok?

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, that was an excellent correction, I didn't notice it :) super thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking, it seems that your condition checker for the status is written incorrectly. Instead of `status = true`, you should use `status == true`. This is because if you try to write it as the latter, it will always be considered *true* and your conditional statement will not be assessed as false and will not go to the **else** statement.

Also, you are missing a logger if the condition falls into the **else** statement. Is this expected? If not, you can try adding it.

Comment: But still I'm getting an empty out put

Comment: @Miyer When you are running your code, does it return any error?